# Output colored text in both sh and bash

Tags: bash, colors, sh

Typically I use:

```
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
```

in bash to achieve the desired effect, but I'm having to rewrite my script to run in sh on a Unix platform now. So I'm looking for a solution with will work in both sh and bash.

Thanks

Comment: That line would work fine in any POSIX-compliant shell. What is the exact error you are encountering?

Comment: No error, just no color change.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. The single line you posted is perfectly valid POSIX code, so either some other part of your script is incorrect, or you have a terminal issue unrelated to the shell you are using.

Comment: Hmm. I use putty to connect into the Unix box via SSH. Logging into a Linux box using the same method works fine. If I issue this command without quotes on the linux box, the terminal color changes as expected to yellow "tput setaf 3". If I try the same thing on the Unix box (again just at command prompt), no result. This eliminates the script, and how I am accessing the box, but not the shell potentially. The Unix box (Well NanoBSD) is a pfSense device, and the default shell is /bin/sh

Comment: Could tput be something that is not included in NanoBSD?

Comment: `tput` simply outputs a string of bytes to standard output, which your terminal interprets as instructions to change the text color. The shell has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Well I take back what I said last time. When I type in tput, it does recognize the command: usage: tput [-T term] attribute ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on `tput` you can simply use the universal [ANSI code sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).  Instead of generating those sequences you can simply assign them using default values like how it's done in this [script](http://sourceforge.net/p/playshell/code/ci/master/tree/source/console.sh).  Just mind that some dumb, old or non-compliant terminals may not support these sequences.

Example:

```
YELLOW="(ESC)[33m"
NORMAL="(ESC)[0m"
```

Or in Bash:

```
YELLOW=$'\e[33m'
NORMAL=$'\e[0m'
```

And then have:

```
echo "${YELLOW}Yellow text.${NORMAL}"
```

`(ESC)` represents a literal ESCAPE char.  Replace it with a real one.  Older shells do not support the `$'\x'` syntax but you can simply use a literal ESCAPE character.  It can be generated using `printf '\e'`.  Redirect the output to a temporary file and open the file with your favorite editor.

Comment: Can you give examples?

Comment: @Atomiklan See update. You can get an escape char by doing `printf "\e" > temp_file` then using an editor to open the file and copy the character from there.

Comment: It apparently did not like that. Here was the output from that direct cut and paste example: (ESC)[33mYellow text.(ESC)[0m

Comment: @Atomiklan Like I said you need to put a real escape char there.

Comment: Oh duh. Wow, sorry missed that

Comment: I always use \ as an escape character. That doesn't seem to work in this situation though. Am I missing something obvious again? YELLOW="\\[33m"

Comment: `"\e"` needs to be interpreted by the shell to produce the actual escape character but doesn't always happen in all shells. `$'\e'` syntax recognizes it but probably only in Bash. If `-e` is supported by `echo`, you can also use it: `echo -e "\e[33m..."`. It would translate `\e` to a real escape char before printing. `printf` as well recognizes it. To allow it to be available in all shells you have to place a raw ESC char instead.